# Converting script argument which is relative to absolute path in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am executing script like this:

```
c:\temp\dir1>c:\myprogram\script1.bat .\subdir1
```

Now in my script1.bat I would like to convert the parameter (%1) which is ".\subdir1" in this case to absolute path so that it would be c:\temp\dir1\subdir1. I have tried various options including %~dp1 and it doesn't give me the desired path here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `for /?`:

```
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
```

Therefore, this should work:

```
for /F %%I in ("%1") do echo %%~fI
```

And actually you don't need the `for`, it can be simplified down to:

```
echo %~f1
```

Comment: This will only work if the `%1` term is a folder in the current directory, otherwise the path will be incorrect.  `echo %~f1` alone will give you the same information as the command above (that's a 1 and not an I)

Comment: @foxidrive it works with any relative path, not just subfolders. `..\..\foo\bar.txt` would work, for example. Thanks for `echo %~f1` though, edited to add.